# Convert Jquery function to AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a function which triggers an event after user has finished typing. The implementation is done on Jquery but i want to convert it to AngularJS. Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm using the AngularJS version of 1.4.3. Here is the function:

```
(function($){
$.fn.extend({
    donetyping: function(callback,timeout){
        timeout = timeout || 1e3; // 1 second default timeout
        var timeoutReference,
            doneTyping = function(el){
                if (!timeoutReference) return;
                timeoutReference = null;
                callback.call(el);
            };
        return this.each(function(i,el){
            var $el = $(el);
            // Chrome Fix (Use keyup over keypress to detect backspace)
            // thank you @palerdot
            $el.is(':input') && $el.on('keyup keypress paste',function(e){
                // This catches the backspace button in chrome, but also prevents
                // the event from triggering too preemptively. Without this line,
                // using tab/shift+tab will make the focused element fire the callback.
                if (e.type=='keyup' && e.keyCode!=8) return;

                // Check if timeout has been set. If it has, "reset" the clock and
                // start over again.
                if (timeoutReference) clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
                timeoutReference = setTimeout(function(){
                    // if we made it here, our timeout has elapsed. Fire the
                    // callback
                    doneTyping(el);
                }, timeout);
            }).on('blur',function(){
                // If we can, fire the event since we're leaving the field
                doneTyping(el);
            });
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why its downvoted?

Comment: Probably because you asking others to convert that code to angularjs for you. Instead of providing info how far you've gotten on your own

Comment: I have done the changes to some extent but thats not working. And that is the reason i have not provided that code. The only function "donetyping" is a tough part for me to convert.

Comment: You can use the` ng-blur`, `ng-change` and `ng-model-option` for this. No need to check if user has stopped typing.

Comment: @Ashish Exactly! Either by using `ng-blur` or using `$timeout` with ng-change (some validations of course) it works fine..

Comment: @Ashish ng-model-option/debounce is a good option. But what i understood it sets the delay on the model change. So it does not wait for the user to stop typing. The very first time the model gets change, the timer starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do by using `ng-blur` (i.e, function triggers when textbox gets out of focus)

```
    <input ng-model="test" ng-blur="search()"/>
```

Or by using `ng-keyup` (i.e, function triggers on every key press)

```
    <input ng-model="test" ng-keyup="search()"/>
```

You can try it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r74a5m25/461/) on jsfiddle for entire code..

Comment: down-voted for?

Comment: Thank you for you inputs. But keyup while fire the event with every key press. I wanted to fire the event once the user has stopped typing.

Comment: ng-blur is for that purpose, of course when user finishes typing he will click else where, that moment the function will trigger

Comment: Thanks! Keep up the good answering :)

Comment: Joe try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/r74a5m25/469/) it will wait for user for 2 seconds on every key-press + some validations it will work like charm :)
Still i suggest `ng-blur` is best option

Comment: @NikhilZurunge, With some tweeks i 'm able to make it work.

Comment: Kudos! Happy coding.. @Joe